# $_POST не возвращает ничего

Tags: php, post

Я хочу подключить сайт к интеркассе.

При обращении к $_POST['ik_sign'] он ничего не выдает

```
<?php

$data = include 'Applications/MyApp/MyApp.php';


// $account = explode(':',$_POST['ik_x_login']);
$dataSet = $_POST;

if (!$dataSet) {
    exit('Произошла ошибка платежа. Обратитесь к администрации сервера');
}


#$key = $_POST['ik_sign'];
$key = $data['unitpay']['privatekey'];


unset($dataSet['ik_sign']); //Delete string with signature from dataset
ksort($dataSet, SORT_STRING); // Sort elements in array by var names in alphabet queue
array_push($dataSet, $key); // Adding secret key at the end of the string
$signString = implode(':', $dataSet); // Concatenation calues using symbol ":"
$sign = base64_encode(hash('sha256', $signString, true)); // Get sha256 hash as binare view using generate string and code it in BASE64


exit("Answer: " . $dataSet['ik_sign']);
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а как вы данные в POST передаёте?

Comment: Покажите как отправляете запрос и получаете ответ. Данный код бесполезный, проблема не верном подходе